# Cluster Health is Green but shard document count and size is not showing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic cluster with 2 nodes with each configured to act as data node as well as master node.

**Cluster Configuration:**

```
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 0
```

The shards are distributed across the 2 nodes as follows:

```
node.ixca_cm_vmops15 : 2 3
node.ixca_cm_vmops16 : 0 1 4
```

I did `GET /_cat/shards` and got the following:

```
   p4_search 2 p STARTED 6251210 104.1gb 10.200.144.76 node.ixca_cm_vmops15 
   p4_search 0 p STARTED 5413272  93.8gb 10.200.144.78 node.ixca_cm_vmops16 
   p4_search 3 p STARTED                 10.200.144.76 node.ixca_cm_vmops15 
   p4_search 1 p STARTED 6205783 103.5gb 10.200.144.78 node.ixca_cm_vmops16 
   p4_search 4 p STARTED 6247744 104.8gb 10.200.144.78 node.ixca_cm_vmops16
```

The cluster health is green.

```
/_cluster/health?pretty=1

{
  "cluster_name" : "p4_cluster",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 5,
  "active_shards" : 5,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

Why does `shard 3` on `node.ixca_cm_vmops15` no show the document count and the shard size?

Comment: Can you post response for cat/_nodes

Comment: @jay The `_cat/nodes` response is follows-
`ixca-cm-vmops15 10.200.144.76 61 25  d * node.ixca_cm_vmops15 
ixca-cm-vmops16 10.200.144.78 69 48  d m node.ixca_cm_vmops16 `